# Restkit multipartFormRequestWithObject not sending correct parameters

Tags: ios, restkit, multipartform-data, restkit-0.20

```
if (image){
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [manager multipartFormRequestWithObject:recipe method:RKRequestMethodPOST path:@"/api/recipes/" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData: UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
                                    name:@"assets[image_url]"
                                fileName:@"image.png"
                                mimeType:@"image/png"];
    }];
    RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [manager objectRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:nil failure:nil];
    [manager enqueueObjectRequestOperation:operation]; // NOTE: Must be enqueued rather than started
} else {
    [manager postObject:recipe path:@"/api/recipes/" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
        NSLog(@"mappingResult: %@", mappingResult);
    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
}
```

This is my post request. Everything works great except when it is an image, a part is missing. 
My recipe class has 3 positions. Within that position there are directions. 
When it is an image, the last position's direction gets cut off. I am not sure why this happens.

Any idea why this could be the case? Am I sending the image in the correct manner?

Updated to provide logs of the Recipe object.

**Without image.**

[image: Recipe log]

**With image.**

[image: Recipe log with image]

To reiterate, everything shows up as expected except the last position's(index 2) direction does not when it is an image. As you can see the recipe object is similar apart from the image aspect.

Comment: Give some more details about the source object (a log of its contents) and the data that hits the wire in both cases if you send that object with and without an image.

Comment: @Wain I have edited my question with the logs.